# Firestore document in a sub-collection, instead of being edited, a new document is added using FormGroup form in Angular this is my function

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, formgroups

I'm trying to update an existing document in a Firestore sub-collection. But instead of editing the document, it adds a new one. I'm using set with merge. Here's my code:

ts file (excerpted)

```
contactsForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactsForm = this.fb.group({
      contactId: ["", Validators.required],
      name: ["", Validators.required],
      email: ["", Validators.email],
      phone: ["", Validators.required],
      type: this.fb.control("type")
    })
editContactInfo() {
    const newContactRef = this.afs.collection('agencies')
      .doc(this.agencyId)
      .collection<Contacts>('contacts').doc(this.contactsForm.value.contactId);
    newContactRef.set({
      name: this.contactsForm.value.name,
      email: this.contactsForm.value.email,
      phone: this.contactsForm.value.phone,

          },{merge: true});
    console.log(this.contactsForm.value)
     }
```

my template

```
<div clrForm [formGroup]="contactsForm" >
 <clr-input-container >
      <label>Contact ID</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="contactId"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container >
      <label>Contact Name</label>
      <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="name"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Contact Email</label>
      <input clrInput type="email" formControlName="email"/>
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
      <label>Contact Phone</label>
      <input clrInput type="phone" formControlName="phone"/>
   </clr-input-container>
    <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" (click)="editContactInfo()">Submit</button>
         </div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I realize now that I need to specify which document I want to edit. I've edited the code accordingly.
I still don't love the fact that the user has to provide the contactId, but since I need to keep this information confidential and not display it in the editForm, I don't see another option.

Answer (score 0):

To update the existing document, you must get the document through some means as this often involves reading the document or collection first, and storing the ID inside the client app as needed to reference as the document to update or link with another document.